# Plotly DASH Tutorial --> Callback missing Inputs in Twitter Sentiment Analysis

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, sentiment-analysis, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial on dash: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz2zqXFjOrE

**Text Tutorial with Code:** https://pythonprogramming.net/live-graph-twitter-sentiment-analysis-gui-dash-python/

The error I was getting earlier was something about not being able to read null values but that change to the following error:

*A callback is missing Inputs.
In the callback for output(s):
live-graph.figure
there are no `Input` elements.
Without `Input` elements, it will never get called.
Subscribing to `Input` components will cause the
callback to be called whenever their values change.*

The tweepy code with the credentials is working fine! Running as it should, so the issue will most likely be in the dash file in the tutorial.

**What I changed in the tutorial code:**

Event no longer exists in Dash, so I *changed all mentions of the word Event to Input*.
I also changed the callback to the following:

*@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
events=[Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])*

Then I put a dummy input into the function (since I believed it didn't need a real input, but this may be where I'm wrong, not sure):

*def update_graph_scatter(graph_update)* instead of def update_graph_scatter( )

I'm super SUPER new to dash, so if anyone updated with the latest libraries could help me out, I would be really thankful !

Answer (score 0):

`@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'), events=[Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])`
This is an improvement, but you can completely remove the `events=` part, that's incorrect.

`def update_graph_scatter(graph_update) instead of def update_graph_scatter( )`
Good fix. The number of inputs in your callback must be the same as the number of parameters in your function.

The rest of the code looks ok to me, so I think it will work once you take the `events=` out.